# Explode a variable and save its parts in windows command line script

Tags: command-line

I need to prompt for three variables in my batch script:

```
set /p artist=Artist:
set /p album=Album:
set /p title=Title:
```

However, variable `%~1` equals `<Artist> - <Album> - <Title>`

Is there a way I explode this variable and get the parts?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out and I'm posting the information for others if they find it useful.

```
REM Remove extension and full path
SET file=%~1
SET file=%file:.mp3=%
For %%A in ("%file%") do (SET file=%%~nxA)

REM : Get artist, album, and title from filename
REM : Only one character deliminator can be used, so replace " - " to "*" first
SET ftemp=%file: - =*%
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=*" %%a in ("%ftemp%") do set artist=%%a&set title=%%b&set key=%%c&set ref=%%d
```